# Fixed points of subgroups of $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{C}^n)$ that are connected complex manifolds

Tags: complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables

Let $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{C}^n)$ be the group of holomorphic automorphisms of $\mathbb{C}^n$. For which subgroups $H$ of $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{C}^n)$ do the fixed points of $H$ acting on $\mathbb{C}^n$, $\operatorname{Fix}(H)$, form a connected complex submanifold of $\mathbb{C}^n$? What are some necessary or sufficient conditions for a subgroup of $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{C}^n)$ to have this property?(*)

(*) Changed in light of YCor's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/409570/fixed-points-of-subgroups-of-mathrmaut-mathbbcn-that-are-connected-com#comment1050790_409570) about criteria.

Comment: What are homomorphic automorphisms?

Comment: @FriedrichKnop holomorphic bijective maps whose inverse is also holomorphic

Comment: I don't know what you (OP) mean by "criteria for identifying them". Identifying what? automorphisms? subgroups of automorphisms? "what are criteria" doesn't make much sense in any case.

Comment: Actually I was confused by "identifying", which I interpreted as "finding some equivalence relation so as to make an identification", while I now understand (after your edit) that you meant "identify" as "recognize".

Comment: As indicated in @FriedrichKnop's [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/409570/fixed-points-of-subgroups-of-mathrmaut-mathbbcn-that-are-connected-com#comment1050783_409570), I think that $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb C^n)$ is meant to consist of *holomorphic*, not *homomorphic*, automorphisms, and have edited accordingly.

Comment: @LSpice, Oops! Thanks! And to Friedrich Knop and YCor too. Even after their comments I still read it as "holomorphic"!

Comment: Finiteness of point-stabilizers is an easy sufficient condition for $Fix(H)$ to be a submanifold. Otherwise, there is an abundant supply of counter-examples once $n\ge 2$ (constructed using holomorphic flows). It's totally unclear to me what kind of an answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 5):

The only sufficient criterion I can think of is the case when $H$ is cyclic of prime power order. Then $Fix(H)$ is a smooth and complex (this holds for any compact group) but also connected by Smith theory.

**Edit** I just checked that Smith theory actually works for arbitrary finite $p$-groups.